# Error in coefficients for a polynomial using Numpy

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, polynomial-math, polynomials

I am using the `numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial` class (Numpy library) in order to fit with the method `fit()` certain data to a polynomial function. The polynomial obtained is all right and I can plot it and substitute points in order to get the ‘y’ value, and I get correct responses. The problem is that the `.coef` attribute of the `Polynomial` class returns a set of coefficients that are somehow normalized or changed and I cant see how. What do I mean? The code follows:

```
x_vid = array([0.0, 50.0, 75.0, 100.0])
y_vid = array([0.0, 30.0, 55.0, 100.0])
pol = Polynomial.fit(x_vid, y_vid, 5) # The polynomial is OK!!
print  pol.coef
```

The `.coef` attribute returns the next array:

```
30   38.16   17.93   9.98    2.06   1.85
```

The coefficients are in increasing order so, so those coefficients represent the following polynomial function:

> 30 + 38.16x + 17.93x^2 + 9.98x^3 + 2.06x^4 + 1.85x^5

However and here comes the problem, if I substitute any value from my range of values [0-100] there, it will not return the proper value, despite that if I do for example:

`pol(0)` → I will get a 0 which is OK, but it is immediate to see that in the polynomial I have written, it will not return 0 at x=0.

I think the polynomial function might be normalized or displaced. I might be facing here a mathematical problem here instead of a programming one, but any help is really welcome, because I need to write down the polynomial and I am not sure of the correct form of it. Thanks.

More info:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.html#numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial

Comment: Did you try using [`numpy.polyfit`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html)? Also, I don't get the same coefficients as you, mine are two orders of magnitude larger.

Comment: thanks @darthbith the two methods should be very similar, anyhow the polynomial is well fitted the problem is the coefficients to write the polynomial function. I have corrected the two orders of magnitude I divided by 100 for different reasons at the time.

Comment: I found the coefficients returned by `polyfit` were reasonable and the y-intercept matched the value of `polyval(pol, 0)`. I have no idea what the coefficients returned from the `Polynomial.fit()` method are

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Polynomial coefficients are for scaled and offset polynomials for improved numerical stability. You can either convert to a "normal" polynomial, or use the series directly if you substitute `off + scl*x` for `x`, where `off` and `scl` are returned by `pol.mapparms`. To convert to standard form (not recomended), do `pol.convert(domain=[-1, 1])`.

Comment: Exactly! Thank you very much Charles Harris

Answer (score 1):

Ruips.

There are three problems with your example:

1. You're fitting a fifth order polynomial with only four data points. This is a case of underdetermination, and it's likely to produce RankWarnings. This is incidental, though, and not the main part of your problem.
2. You expect `pol(0)` to work like `numpy.polyval`, but it doesn't. I'm actually not sure what it does. The class provides a `__call__`, which makes `pol(0)` work, but as far as I can tell there's no documentation for the callable (see [Polynomial docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.__call__.html#numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.__call__)). `numpy.polynomial.polynomial` contains its own version of `polyval`. I will test it, `np.polyval` and a homebrewed version `test_polyval` together.
3. Most importantly, the `Polynomial` class orders coefficients differently from `numpy.polyfit` and `numpy.polyval`. In `Polynomial`, as you described, the highest order coefficient is last in the list/array. In the `numpy` functions, though, the highest order coefficient is first (see [polyval docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyval.html)).

The code snippet below illustrates how to evaluate the polynomial represented by your `Polynomial` object at an arbitrary set of x-values, and also shows that in order to get the same behavior out of `numpy.polyval`, you have to reverse the order of the coefficients using `coef[::-1]`. I could have equivalently used `numpy.fliplr` to reverse the coefficient order.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial.polynomial import Polynomial,polyval
from numpy import array
import sys


x_vid = array([0.0, 50.0, 75.0, 100.0])
y_vid = array([0.0, 30.0, 55.0, 100.0])
pol = Polynomial.fit(x_vid, y_vid, 5) # The polynomial is OK!!

# I've written this, which should do what numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval 
# does, as a sanity check:
def test_polyval(polynomialInstance,xArray):
    # check that xArray is a numpy.ndarray, using ndarray.shape
    try:
        y = np.zeros(xArray.shape)
    except Exception as e:
        sys.exit('polyval error: %s'%e)

    # manually sum the polynomial terms on xArray
    for exp,c in enumerate(polynomialInstance.coef):
        y = y + c*x**exp

    return y

# Define some random x values for testing, in the range of points used
# for fitting:
x = np.random.rand(100)*100

# Compute, using our own polyval function, then Polynomial.polyval,
# and finally using numpy.polyval, making sure to reverse the
# coefficient order for the last:
y_test_polyval = test_polyval(pol,x)
y_Polynomial_polyval = polyval(x,pol.coef)
y_numpy_polyval = np.polyval(pol.coef[::-1],x)

# Make sure the two results are within machine epsilon:
if np.allclose(y_test_polyval,y_numpy_polyval) and \
        np.allclose(y_test_polyval,y_Polynomial_polyval):
    print 'Hurray!'
```

Comment: I should have said also that I tested the equality of the two `polyval` implementations over many other intervals (smaller and larger than [0,100]) and it works elsewhere too. I think there is a difference between the `Polynomial` class and `numpy.polyfit`/`numpy.polyval`, in terms of fitting, since the former allows you to specify ranges over which the residual errors are computed.

Comment: Also, I did find `Polynomial.polyval`. It was right under my nose: [http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval.html#numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval](here).

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer, but Charles Harris responded exactly what I was asking.